# Syntax error "(" when starting Nodejs global package in Linux Debian

Tags: node.js, linux

I'm using pm2,

install it by `npm install pm2 -g` but when I type `pm2` in terminal

it says Syntax error "("

```
root@beaglebone:/home/IXD/nodeProject/servertest# node-v4.4.7-linux-x86/bin/node: 1: /home/IXD/node-v4.4.7-linux-x86/bin/node: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

and I found every nodejs global package will cause this error

ex:forever nodemon pm2 ...etc

but in windows7 it works fine.